# get final price of configurable super product with catalog rules applied

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, catalog-price-rules, catalog-rules, superattribute

I'll try to explain it in details as it's quite tricky.

Let's say I have configurable product X with price 10, and color variations red and green with fixed price +5 and -5.
So the final price for the red X would be 15 and for the green X would be 5 while for other X colors would be 10.

Now we also apply a catalog rule on the configurable X, for example let's say -3.

So now the final prices would be:
red X: 12
green X: 2
other X colors: 7

I can get the final price of the Configurable(7) by using

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalogrule/rule')->getRulePrice
```

but how can I get the final prices for the other attribute options as well?
Should I recalculate looping through the attributes and their pricing_value and applying them to the discounted price of the base product or is there any easier way?

moreover:
if catalog rule has disabled discount to sub-products then above logic works. Get the base price with the catalog rules applied and apply super attributes prices on top.
but if discount to sub-products is enabled, then how can I get the "pricing_value" of an attribute with catalog rules applied?